# How do I set constraints to a UIImageView with scaleAspectFill such that its height stays within the available space?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I want my UIImageView to always take the full width of the page and aspect fill within the available height. (This page is within a ScrollView)

**[Here's the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK2yK.png) that I am trying to achieve.**

**What I have implemented so far:**

Created a UIView (parent of UIImageView) with the following constraints to break free of the margins on left and right:

```
        let borderViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: page2.topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: page2.leadingAnchor,
                constant: -horizontalPadding),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: page2.trailingAnchor,
                constant: horizontalPadding),
        ]
```

Then, made imgView (UIImageView) a subview of containerView (UIView):

```
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        // ...

        // Setting the constraints 
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: containerView.topAnchor,
                constant: 120),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

**The problem**

The problem with this approach is that since the height of UIView is not bound to anything, the image gets under the title text on smaller screens. Is there a way to bound the height of UIView so as to prevent this overflow?

Comment: You can't constrain the top of the image. You need to allow it to extend off  the top of the screen.  You want a fixed width, a fixed aspect ratio and to fill the area. That extra image has to go somewhere.

Comment: @Paulw11 I understand. I wish to put a max-height on the parent UIView so that I can further set clipToBounds and prevent that overflow from being visible.

Comment: You shouldn’t see the overflow because it will be under the white bar at the top of the screen.  You can’t use clips to bounds on the image view itself because that would mean the top of the image was on the screen. You could add the image view to a UIView, allow the image to extend outside of that view and constrain the UIView to the top of the screen with clips to blues